# card-deck images bootstrap4 not working in IE-11

Tags: internet-explorer, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-cards

Hello I Use simple bootstrap-4 cards code but the images are not displaying properly in IE-11, even i used h-100 for cards but the issue is not resolved

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).According to the W3C Bootstrap 4 Cards tutorial, I created a sample, it works well on IE11. Try to use F12 developer tools to check whether the image is load success? and whether there has some error?

Comment: here is my css code    .card-overlay
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #d4005f75;
}

Comment: Still can't reproduce the problem, can you post the related CSS style and html elements as in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Besides, I created a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/4q58mp7c/) using Bootstrap 4 cards, please refer to it.